# Pandas:Pivot : Is it possible to do calculation on the Pivoted Results?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I have a Pivot table result (pivotDF)

```
colkeys = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.object]).columns.tolist()
colkeys.remove('Department')
measure = ['Commission']

pivotDf = pd.pivot_table(df, index=colkeys, 
                         columns = ['Department'], 
                         values = measure,
                         aggfunc = lambda x: np.sum(x),
                         fill_value = 0)
```

[image: Output of DF and Pivot]

The syntax below seems to generate the diff and the percentage I am after, If I run them after the Pivot table, the last one seems to override the result of the first one.

```
pivotDf.diff(axis=1).iloc[:,[0,1]]
pivotDf.pct_change(axis=1).iloc[:,[0,1]].round(0)
```

I just need two additional columns on the pivot table output showing the difference of the Commission and the percentage difference of the two different departments. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to check... You have to make:

pivotDf = pivotDf.diff(axis=1).iloc[:,[0,1]]

Did you made it?

Comment: I just tried it and it overrides the pivotDF pivot table completely

Comment: Now I understood.
I believe you can make:
pivotDf['Diff'] = (pivotDf['Comission']['Dept2']-pivotDf['Comission']['Dept2'])/pivotDf['Comission']['Dept2']

Comment: Another question I have is, is this the best approach or can I do something else to get the results I am after using Pandas?

Comment: I belive this is the best...

pivotDf = pivotDf.assign(Diff=(pivotDf['A']-pivotDf['B'])/pivotDf['B'])

Comment: Yes, thanks Murilo, it works. much appreciated,

Comment: ok, thanks, it works

Comment: Thats even better, Thanks